# Specify column mapping when loading JSON into Google BigQuery

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

Let's say we have the following JSON object:

```
{"keyA": "1", "keyB": 2}
```

We want to load this into a BigQuery table with two columns; `col_a` and `col_b`.

If the JSON keys and the column names matched, we could just use, for instance, `load_table_from_json` (in the Python client)

But is there any way to specify that values from JSON key `keyA` should be put in `col_a` and `keyB` should be put in `col_b`?

Preferably, I'd like to be able to do this in Python, but this is really a question about the BigQuery API in general.

Answer (score 1):

The API doesn't support column naming.

You can use autodetect

```
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
```

Or you could load as a whole JSON, then use the JSON_EXTRACT methods to create individual columns from it

```
create table `newtable` as
select json_extract(meta,'$.keyA') as keyA ...
```